# how to test rest controller with custom spring DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, junit, dispatcher, mockmvc

I'm trying to test my controller and I want to my custom DispatcherServlet include on that.

my dispatcher is something like this:

```
 public class LoggableDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggableDispatcherServlet.class);
    @Autowired
    private LogsService logsService;
    @Override
    protected void doDispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
     Exception 
    {
         .
         .
         .
         mapper.readTree(requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
         int status = responseWrapper.getStatus();
         JsonNode newNode = mapper.readTree(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
         JsonNode responseJson= newNode;
         logsService.addLogs(request,response ,...)


    }
}
```

and my test Class is something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class RestControllerTest {

    private final Resource test1 = new ClassPathResource("test1.json");

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;


    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
        this.mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(this.restTemplate)
                .build()

    }

    @Test
    public void getAvailableLoanTest() throws Exception{
        String url1="http://localhost:80801/testService?param1=1&param2=2";

        this.mockRestServiceServer
                .expect(ExpectedCount.manyTimes(), requestTo(url1))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(this.test1, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/myApi")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(asJsonString(new MyRequest(1, 2,))))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                //.andExpect(jsonPath("@.res1").value(1L))
                .andReturn(); 


        .
        .
        . 
    }
}
```

The problem is my request receive directly by rest controller and I can't test the DispatcherServlet.
I'm using spring boot 2.2.3 with jar packaging and I don't have web.xml or any servlet configration.

Comment: `MockMvc` uses a special subclass of the `DIspatcherServlet` for this. That being said wouldn't this code be better of in a servlet filter instead of the extended `DispatcherServlet`? That would make it independent testable and quite easy to setup for `MockMvc` as well (it would in this case work out-of-the-box).

Comment: @M.Deinum Correct, That's better use filter in this case but I don't want change all things in LoggableDispatcherServlet now. I want to find solution to test rest controllers with dispatcherServlet with or without MockMvc.

Comment: The only way is to not use MockMvc, as that uses a special `TestDispatcherServlet`. So you would need a full-blown integration test. However I would still recommend moving all that logic into a filter which would be a lot easier (and is where it belongs in the first place imho). ANother thing is yu are testing the controller but also the servlet? You shouldn't do multiple things in a single test, next to that it is an `@SpringBootTest` and you should `@Autowire` the `MockMvc` not create it yourself (you are mixing things in this test).